# How to transform 'double' into 'cell array'?

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, dimensions, cell-array

My code:

```
B = zeros(height(A),1);
col_names = A.Properties.VariableNames; % Replicate header names 
for k = 1:height(A)
    % the following 'cellfun' compares each column to the values in A.L{k},
    % and returns a cell array of the result for each of them, then
    % 'cell2mat' converts it to logical array, and 'any' combines the
    % results for all elements in A.L{k} to one logical vector:
    C = any(cell2mat(...
        cellfun(@(x) strcmp(col_names,x),A.L{k},...
        'UniformOutput', false).'),1);
    % then a logical indexing is used to define the columns for summation:
    B(k) = sum(A{k,C});
end
```

generates the following error message.

```
Error using cellfun
Input #2 expected to be a cell array, was double instead.
```

How do I solve this error?

This is how table 'A' looks like:
[image]

A.L{1,1} contains:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure quite what's going on here, but here's a fabricated example that I *think* is similar to what you're trying to achieve.

```
%% Setup - fabricate some data
colNames = {'xx', 'yy', 'zz', 'qq'};
h = 20;
% It looks like 'L' contains something related to the column names
% so I'm going to build something like that.
L = repmat(colNames, h, 1);
% Empty some rows out completely
L(rand(h,1) > 0.7, :) = {''};
% Empty some other cells out at random
L(rand(numel(L), 1) > 0.8) = {''};
A = table(L, rand(h,1), rand(h, 1), rand(h, 1), rand(h, 1), ...
    'VariableNames', ['L', colNames]);

%% Attempt to process each row
varNames = A.Properties.VariableNames;
B = zeros(height(A), 1);
for k = 1:height(A)
    % I think this is what's required - work out which columns are
    % named in "A.L(k,:)". This can be done simply by using ISMEMBER
    % on the row of A.L.
    C = ismember(varNames, A.L(k,:));
    B(k) = sum(A{k, C});
end
```

If I'm completely off-course here, then perhaps you could give us an executable example.

Comment: If this is along the right lines, then there might be a way to avoid the loop over the table rows, but I'm not sure...

Comment: Very helpful, @Edric! I understand your reasoning, but in my case the following error occurred: `Error using cell/ismember (line 34)
Input A of class cell and input B of class cell must be cell arrays of character vectors, unless one is a character
vector.`

Comment: I haven't got the right form for `A.L` then. I can't quite work out from your description what each row of `A.L` looks like. I suspect for you `iscellstr(A.L(1,:))` returns `false`, which is a problem. Could you post some code that builds a representative `A.L`? Are there non-strings in `A.L`?

Comment: `iscellstr(A.L(1,:));` returns logical 0.
In fact what A.L contains is header names of table A that fulfill certain criteria. (see extract of A.L{1,1} above)

Answer (score 1):

```
C = any(cell2mat(...
    cellfun(@(x) strcmp(col_names,x),A.L{k},...
    'UniformOutput', false).'),1);
```

here `A.L{k}` gets the contents of the cell located at the kth position of `A.L`. Using `A.L(k)` you get the cell itself which is located at `A.L`:

```
tmp = A.L(k);
C = any(cell2mat(...
    cellfun(@(x) strcmp(col_names,x),tmp{1},...
    'UniformOutput', false).'),1);
```

Bit of a hacky way, as you first need to get the cell at `A.L(k)` and *then* need the contents of that cell, so you need a temporary variable.

Comment: Doing so now generates a problem with my strcmp() section. 
`Error using strcmp
Inputs must be the same size or either one can be a scalar.
Error in @(x)strcmp(col_names,x)`

Comment: @John what is the contents of `A.L{k}`? As in: what is contained in those 27 cells? Because I suspect its contents are numbers, your `doubles` MATLAB complains about, whilst you expected some kind of string there, in which case your code as posted in the question should work.

Comment: A.L{k} contains header names of table A that fulfill certain characteristics (I uploaded an extract of A.L{1,1} above so you can see)

Comment: @John I updated. It is possible this way, but I suggest taking a careful look at Edric's answer, as it probably solves your case a lot faster and less obfuscated.